# JQuery is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have below code in my html and it works fine when I open that file as website from visual studio. But when I double clicked Test.html and open it in IE, it does not work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Print Me That Label</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function clickMe()
            {
                alert("Clicked");
                var labelXml = "test";
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.get("DZLabel.xml", function (labelXml) {
                        alert("Clicked1");
                        document.getElementById("labelTextArea").innerText = labelXml;
                    }, "text");
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="labelTextArea">Text on the label:</label>
        <textarea name="labelTextArea" id="labelTextArea" rows='2'></textarea>
        <button id='printButton' onclick="clickMe()">CLICK</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here id `DZLabel.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips">
  <PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation>
  <Id>Address</Id>
 </DieCutLabel>
```

Is there anything wrong with my IE setting?

Comment: Ajax requests wont work for *local* files opened via the file system (as opposed to over http)

Comment: does it work in chrome/others?

Comment: When you double clicked Test.html, what address appears in Internet Explorer address bar?

Comment: There is no point whatsoever to having a `ready` callback *inside* a click handler (at least, not for the same page).

Comment: jQuery 1.4.3 is 4 years old. Try using the current version.

Comment: it never goes to this line alert("Cliked1"); when I open Test.html in IE (by double clicking on it), But in chrome it does alert on Clicked1 but labelXml is blank in chrome

Comment: jbutler483, pls provide solution how can I achieve this, so I can run directly in IE or chrome, and don not have to use visual studio

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I know, i was just trying diff options,

Comment: not working with this http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
document.getElementById("labelTextArea").value = labelXml;
```

not innerHtml.

That worked for me.

Comment: it never goes to this line alert("Cliked1"); when I open Test.html in IE (by double clicking on it)

Comment: exactly the same, what you posted. maybe try to update your jquery as others mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `jquery code` like,

```
$(function(){  
    $('#printButton').bind('click',function(){
        $.get("DZLabel.xml", function (labelXml) {
            alert("Cliked1");
            $("#labelTextArea").val(labelXml);
        }, "text");
    });    
});
```